# Asking code suggestions about data structure and algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, stack

I recently posted an entry here in stackoverflow for a specific problem I've encountered after run and did asked a few. It's a similar one but this time I need your thoughts and comments to atleast better up my programming skills. For those who didn't know  I'm new at coding in C so some conventions in this language were new to me due to the fact that I got introduce to high level language such as Python and Java first. Suggestions and criticisms are highly appreciated.

The code below is about stacks from Data Structure and Algorithms and I wrote this code to understand how the algorithm work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXSIZE 5

int y = 5;
int z = 10;
struct stack
{
    int a[MAXSIZE];
    int Top;
};

void push(struct stack *pU)
{
    int size;
    const int x = 4; // Each element is 4 bytes 

    pU->Top = -1;
    size = sizeof(pU->a[pU->Top]) / x;

    if(size > MAXSIZE)
    {
        printf("stack is full\n");
        exit(2);
    } else {
    /*
     * First Element
     */
        pU->a[++pU->Top] = y;
        printf("Top element: %d\n", pU->a[pU->Top]);

    /*
     * Second Element
     */
    pU->a[++pU->Top] = z;
    printf("New top element: %d\n", pU->a[pU->Top]);
    }

    /*
     * Count index of array 
     */
    for(int i = -1; i <= pU->Top; ++i)
    {
        if(pU->a[i] >= 0 && pU->a[i] <= 99)
    {
        size = size + 1;

        if(size > MAXSIZE)
        {
                printf("Stack is full\n");
            exit(2);
        } else if(size == size){
            printf("Number of elements in array: %d\n", size);
        }
    }
    break;
    }

}

void pop(struct stack *pO)
{
    int size;
    const int x = 4;

    for(int i = 0; i < 1; ++i)
    {
         pO->Top = pO->Top - 1;  // Decrement Top
     printf("Recently added stack removed. Current stack is: %d\n", pO->a[pO->Top]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct stack *M;
    
    push(M);
    pop(M);
}
```

Comment: What's the question? Does the code work? Are you just looking to have it reviewed? If so, Code Review is the place for that. Otherwise, please provide info on what goes wrong and what should happen.

Comment: The basic philosophy of a stack is that you pass a value in on the call to `push`, and get a value returned on calls to `pop`. Your code does neither of these. Also the stack itself should keep track of its free space, by a simple count. you do not need that calculation `size = sizeof(pU->a[pU->Top]) / x;`, you just need a counter managed in the two functions.